# Failover in AG without listener

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

We have SQL Servers with versions SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2019. We already check that we can do failover on SQL Server 2019 without listener but I can not test it on SQL Server 2016. Do you know if it is also possible ?

Comment: The listener simplifies and directs connections for the clients, it is not required for a failover to work.  I've not directly tested this but I have no reason to believe that it wouldn't work.  I guess you are using the Failover Group Cluster Name instead of a Listener?  The listener's only real advantage is that it understands read-intent and can be controlled by SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A listener is not required for a failover as @JonathanFite mentioned in comments. I just ran a quick test on a lab AG without a listener and it succeeded without issues.

On a side note, I suggest you create a lab environment for testing AG configurations and automation scripts. This can be entirely virtualized with Developer Edition to reduce infrastructure and licensing costs.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. On which version of SQL Server 2016 did you test ?

Comment: @adam.g, I tested with SQL Server 2019 multi-subnet failover cluster. I don't have a lab handy for older versions but I wouldn't expect differences.